# Cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: wireless, internet

My desktop has Broadband wired connection - shows connected, but unable to load any web page in Ubuntu 12.04 but works fine with Windows 7.

My laptop - wireless connection shows connected, but again does not load any web page.

Please help. On running sudo dhclient eth1 on my laptop there is no result - see the screen output:prajna@LAPTOP:~$ sudo dhclient eth1 
[sudo] password for prajna: 
prajna@LAPTOP:~$ sudo dhclient eth1 
[sudo] password for prajna:
after giving password - some time later the screen comes back to
prajna@LAPTOP:~$

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please can you update your question with the details about your hardware and version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Try to turn your wifi off and on again (with hardware switch if you have one). I'm having the same problem since 12.04 sometimes. I was to lazy to look into it though. I was just thinking it maybe the same error.

Comment: ubuntu version is 12.04, my desk top connection modem is "wan miniport (PPPoE)" - please explain what further detials do you want? i have taken the connection details from WIN7 & entered them manually in Ubuntu

Comment: tried the wifi switch on / off - no joy

Comment: my laptop - through wireless, & my desktop through broad band phone cable. Even if only one of them is connected still i can not access the web.

Comment: Can you add output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.  Also, (1) can you connect to the internet with any services besides the browser?, and (2) can you paste the error message your browser gives when it fails to load a web page?

Comment: On running cat /etc/resolv.conf - pls see result:prajna@LAPTOP:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN 
nameserver 127.0.0.1 
1) I can not connect to the net for any services

Comment: 2) error message given by browser:Server not found
 Firefox can't find the server at start.ubuntu.com.
  Check the address for typing errors such as
    ww.example.com instead of
    www.example.com
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: PLEASE HELP GUYS

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Comment: guess that would be `sudo dhclient wlan0`

Comment: tried the "sudo dhclient wlan0" on my laptop - reply was cannot find device wlan0

Comment: 0f course wlan0, sorry for the mistake. So it looks like you have no "device". So it is important you tell us what hardware do you have.

Comment: i have a sony viao laptop - with an inbuilt wireless card

Comment: please see details from my laptop after running nm-tool:
prajna@LAPTOP:~$ nm-tool
NetworkManager Tool
State: connected (global)
- Device: eth1  [UTStarcom]   Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ipw2200
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:13:CE:68:AD:F3
  Capabilities:
  Wireless Properties    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *UTStarcom:      Infra, 00:1B:57:F0:03:75, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60

Comment: IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         117.197.208.209
    Prefix:          32 (255.255.255.255)
    Gateway:         117.197.208.1
    DNS:             218.248.255.209

Comment: Device: eth0 
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e100
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:01:4A:C2:89:E5

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

Comment: hello Misery, ran iwconfig, please see result:    prajna@LAPTOP:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"UTStarcom"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:1B:57:F0:03:75   
Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   Sensitivity=8/0  
Retry limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=60/100  Signal level=-25 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
eth0      no wireless extensions.
Can you Please Help??

Comment: Ok, looks like your wireless interface is eth1.  Try `sudo dhclient eth1`, and paste the output in your original question.

Comment: have pasted the output in original questio